# Controller Method not showing the web form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following action method in my controller:

```cs
public RedirectResult OnlineInvoice(string PickupNo)
{   
    return Redirect("/ReportsWebForms/frmReportOnlineInvoice.aspx?PickupNo=" + 102);
}
```

I tried to call that method as following:

```js
$.get("@Url.Action("OnlineInvoice","Report")", { PickupNo : '@ViewBag.PickupNo'});
```

and

```js
$.post("@Url.Action("OnlineInvoice","Report")", { PickupNo : '@ViewBag.PickupNo'});
```

I put a break point on the action method and I can see that is called, however the webform is not showing, the website still showing the current view.
But if I call that method via a link as in:

```html
<a href="/Report/OnlineInvoice">Report</a>
```

The web form is loaded normally!

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot issue a redirect on AJAX by doing that. You are calling an AJAX request on your javascript.

The problem is, it is returning a redirect request on your controller and AJAX request cannot interpret that. You need to return a JSON on your controller using JsonResult and pass the URL where you want to redirect.

Then from your get request on your Javascript, retrieve the url and you can use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.yourpassurlhere.com";
```